# Redirect user to different pages, or Bring all together in 1 page?

Tags: usability, website-design, interface

I'm about to create a web platform. Users can just either sign-up or login and start using the web app right away. (client side is AngularJS)

I've always wondered this. Does a web developer should make a different page for each section of their site and have their user jump from this page to another, or just create 1-2 main pages and then load external links/different sections on same page? (with using something like Ajax, hope you know what i mean)

Not just from **UX** perspective, also trying to get an idea on how does it affect the **Page loading speed**, **SEO** and other things..

This:

> index.html
>
> --main.html
>
> ----profile.html
>
> ----search.html
>
> ----profile.html
>
> ----search.html
>
> etc...

or just have this and change the content depending on user action (using tabs, navigations menus,etc..):

> index.html

is this considered a modern UX ? Does it even make sense?

Comment: It seems you're talking about single page applications. This will help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21862054/single-page-application-advantages-and-disadvantages

Answer (score 1):

Just one page loading needed elements makes your life not easier:

- Seo: Isnt possible anymore as bots wont get all elements. Your websites will apear as just one single page - the starting page with its keywords. No mpre keywords possible. Thats the complete opposite of a landingpage....
- Users: Cant use search engines to jump directly into your pages. They are forced to start with your start page. Cant bookmark any more and are very likely to loose any orientation because back-button is most used button in the web. Common concepts like pages are disturbed, because it doesnt behave like a jumpt to next page.
- Analytics: Will be a completly mess. So you could get any easy insights into user paths and page visits. You could get insights, but not using the standard reports.

Personaly, I think it is a hot developer dream making everything dynamic as requested. It is technical feasable but lacks any user need.

It actually makes sense for application webpages or rich internet apps, where you need to work like the photoshop.com app. But not for common informational pages.